# Magento 2 - Changing the packing slip pdf print out layout

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, pdf, create-invoice, invoice-pdf

I am trying to edit the template of packing slip pdf print file.

Basically the part that I am interested is the height of product description area.

I traced back the parts that create font size or box height, but I am not sure how I should edit it. Obviously I am not looking for editing them on Magento core and I am trying to edit the parts in a custom module.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php#L88

for example on this line the `$this->y` & `$this->y - 15` are the rectangle height for the pdf print out in `products` area.

I tried to create an `Invoice.php` file in my custom module under

> MY_MODULE\Model\Order\Pdf

and copy/paste the content of [git repo file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php) there and did the edit, but it did't work. I know how to change the xml layouts but technically I am not sure how I should edit this type of files.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible yo change the layout of pdfslip by using Model file.
edit, create a di.xml file under `MY\MODULE\etc\adminhtml\`
and edit it as followed

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="MY\MODULE\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" /> 
</config>
```

After that create a Invoice.php file under `MY\MODULE\Model\Order\Pdf`
and change it like this

```
<?php

namespace MY\MODULE\Model\Order\Pdf;

class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{

    protected function _doDrawHeader(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
    {
        /* Add table head */
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y + 5, 570, $this->y - 25);
        $this->y -= 10;
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0, 0, 0));

        //columns headers
        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Products'), 'feed' => 35];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('SKU'), 'feed' => 290, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Qty'), 'feed' => 435, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Price'), 'feed' => 360, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Tax'), 'feed' => 495, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Subtotal'), 'feed' => 565, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 5];

        $this->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true]);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->y -= 20;
    }

    public function getPdf($invoices = [])
    {
        $this->_beforeGetPdf();
        $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

        $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
        $this->_setPdf($pdf);
        $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
        $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                $this->_localeResolver->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
                $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
            }
            $page = $this->newPage();
            $order = $invoice->getOrder();
            /* Add image */
            $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());
            /* Add address */
            $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());
            /* Add head */
            $this->insertOrder(
                $page,
                $order,
                $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                    self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $order->getStoreId()
                )
            );
            /* Add document text and number */
            $this->insertDocumentNumber($page, __('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId());
            /* Add table */
            $this->_doDrawHeader($page);
            /* Add body */
            foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                /* Draw item */
                $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
                $page = end($pdf->pages);
            }
            /* Add totals */
            $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                $this->_localeResolver->revert();
            }
        }
        $this->_afterGetPdf();
        return $pdf;
    }


    /**
     * Create new page and assign to PDF object
     *
     * @param  array $settings
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Page
     */
    public function newPage(array $settings = [])
    {
        /* Add new table head */
        $page = $this->_getPdf()->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
        $this->_getPdf()->pages[] = $page;
        $this->y = 800;
        if (!empty($settings['table_header'])) {
            $this->_doDrawHeader($page);
        }
        return $page;
    }
}
```

As it is editing a protected function `__DrawHeader` you should changes its name, like `_doDrawHeader`. Also you should edit its name in the calling method `$this->_doDrawHeader($page);` in `public function getPdf`